# Data that's not missing is called...?

Tags: data-cleaning, terminology, missing-data

Is there a standard term for data that are not missing? I.e. is it called non-missing, present, or something else?

Comment: hmmm maybe complete?

Comment: Depends on content, but I would probably go for "observed" (vs. "unobserved"). A suitable direct antonym of "missing" might be "extant".

Comment: Very generous :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on content, but I would probably go for "observed" (vs. "unobserved"). A suitable direct antonym of "missing" might be "extant".